# Confusion behind proving triangle inequality

Tags: real-analysis

I'm having some trouble in understanding the intuition behind proving the triangle inequality. I have two examples and I am tasked with proving that they're metric spaces. I can prove everything UP to the triangle inequality.

Example 1: The metric space is all bounded infinite sequences $x = (x_1, ...)$ of elements of $\Bbb R$, with $d(x, y) = l.u.b. (|x_1 - y_1|, ...)$.

I try assigning a fixed value for which the $l.u.b. = |p_k - r_k|$ for some $k$, but I cannot do this as the sequence is infinite. I thought about making the $l.u.b.$ the value at which the infinite sequence terminates, but I haven't gotten very far with that.

Example 2: $(E_1 \times E_2, d)$ where $(E_1, d_1)$ and $(E_2, d_2)$ are metric spaces and $d$ is given by $d((x_1, x_2), (y_1, y_2)) = max (d_1(x_1, y_1), d_2(x_2, y_2))$.

For this one, I first assumed cases, e.g. that $d(x_2, y_2) \gt d(x_1, y_1)$ and moved on from there. However, I soon found myself having too many cases to care for (it seemed to only complicate matters).

How do I prove the triangle inequality for these metric spaces, and is there a general approach for proving the triangle inequality for arbitrary metric spaces (or, are there certain methods favored over others)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the **first example**, for each $n$ we have $|x_n - z_n| \leq |x_n - y_n| + |y_n - z_n|$ by the ordinary triangle inequality on $\mathbb R$. Taking the supremum of each term on the right-hand side, we obtain
$$|x_n - z_n| \leq \sup \{|x_n - y_n| : n \in \mathbb N\} + \sup\{|y_n - z_n| : n \in \mathbb N\} = d(x,y) + d(y,z)$$
This inequality holds for all $n \in \mathbb N$, so the right hand side is an upper bound of the set $\{|x_n - z_n| : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, so the *least* upper bound of that set cannot be any larger:
$$d(x,z) = \sup\{|x_n - z_n| : n \in \mathbb{N}\} \leq d(x,y) + d(y,z)$$

For the **second example**, both $d_1$ and $d_2$ satisfy the triangle inequality, so for $x_1,y_1,z_1 \in E_1$ we have
$$d_1(x_1,z_1) \leq d_1(x_1,y_1) + d_1(y_1,z_1)$$
and for $x_2,y_2,z_2 \in E_2$ we have
$$d_2(x_2,z_2) \leq d_2(x_2,y_2) + d_2(y_2,z_2)$$
Now, both $d_1(x_1,y_1)$ and $d_2(x_2,y_2)$ are no larger than $\max\{d_1(x_1,y_1), d_2(x_2,y_2)\}$. Similarly, both $d_1(y_1,z_1)$ and $d_2(y_2,z_2)$ are no larger than $\max\{d_1(y_1,z_1), d_2(y_2,z_2)\}$. Consequently
$$\max\{d_1(x_1,y_1), d_2(x_2,y_2)\} + \max\{d_1(y_1,z_1), d_2(y_2,z_2)\}$$
is an upper bound for the right-hand sides of both of the above inequalities.
Therefore, it is also an upper bound for both $d_1(x_1,z_1)$ and $d_2(x_2,z_2)$ and consequently also for $\max\{d_1(x_1,z_1), d_2(x_2,z_2)\}$. We conclude that
$$\max\{d_1(x_1,z_1), d_2(x_2,z_2)\} \leq \max\{d_1(x_1,y_1), d_2(x_2,y_2)\} + \max\{d_1(y_1,z_1), d_2(y_2,z_2)\}$$
Referring to the definition of $d$, this is exactly the same as
$$d((x_1,x_2),(z_1,z_2)) \leq d((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2)) + d((y_1,y_2),(z_1,z_2))$$
as desired.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how you derived $|x_n - z_n| \leq \sup \{|x_n - y_n| : n \in \mathbb N\} + \sup\{|y_n - z_n| : n \in \mathbb N\} = d(x,y) + d(y,z)$. How do we know that $ \sup \{|x_n - y_n| : n \in \mathbb N\} + \sup\{|y_n - z_n| : n \in \mathbb N\} = d(x,y) + d(y,z)$?

Comment: @ColeButler Isn't that exactly how they are defined? $d(x,y) = \sup \{|x_1 - y_1|, |x_2 - y_2|, \ldots\} = \sup\{|x_n - y_n| : n \in \mathbb N\}$